# Clarification for Javamelody in Tomcat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, java-melody

I have setup Javamelody in my Tomcat container to view the statistics of my currently used website.

My website is configured in server.xml as follows and is not deployed as war but the classes and the jsp files are manually copied to "/dun/student/webapps" location as shown  in the mapping:

```
<Context path="/stud" docBase="/dun/student/webapps" crossContext="false" debug="0" reloadable="true">
        </Context>
```

I have copied the jar files **javamelody.jar** and **jrobin-1.5.9.1.jar** in the lib directory of my web-app.

Now I have modified the web.xml of my web-app to have the following lines and I have pasted it above my servlet declarations.

```
<filter>
                <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
                <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
```

I have restarted tomcat as well.

Now I'm trying to access my java melody statistics using the url:

```
http://student.studentgrade.com:8080/stud/monitoring
```

But I'm getting a 404 status saying requested resource is not available.

Now my web app which has many jsp files which were working fine too cannot be accessed and there too I'm getting a 404 error.

```
http://student.studentgrade.com:8080/stud/hello.jsp
```

But if I remove those lines which I added for javamelody in the web.xml file my jsp can be accessed.

What am I doing wrong here.

Please advice how I can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you add 
        
                net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener
        
into your web.xml?